Can't update APT because my /etc/apt/sources.list has a malformed line
I am using Ubuntu Mate 24.04.1 and my /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources got messed up and is not allowing me to update APT. What should these files contain so that I can fix what needs to be in them and update APT again?
Here is the output to apt update
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (type)
E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

cat /etc/apt/sources.list the output is:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources output is:
Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 23.10 _Mantic Minotaur_ - Release amd64 (20231010)]/
Suites: mantic
Components: main restricted universe multiverse


Can you please edit your question to include the output of sudo apt update and cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please add the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources to your question

Looks like the comment signs (#'s at the start of each comment line) got deleted for some reason.
However, it looks like /etc/apt/sources.list used to contain only a comment telling you that the new location of the information that used to be there is now /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources. So since you got no error messages about that file, that file is probably OK.
You can probably just replace the contents of the /etc/apt/sources.list file (= the legacy APT repository configuration file) with a descriptive comment:
echo "# Standard Ubuntu repositories now at etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list >/dev/null

Your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources looks like it only contained a reference to an old Ubuntu MATE installation CD/DVD. It's from version 23.10 as opposed to your current 24.04, so it's useless anyway.
Just delete the file:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources


Thank you for the help, I ran the command to replace my apt source file and removed the third party one and all is well on the home front.

I had a similar issue.
The third-party.sources file at /etc/apt/sources.list.d was causing a malformed line error when running software update.
third-party.sources contents:

Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS _Jammy Jellyfish_ - Release amd64 (20220809.1)]/
Suites: jammy
Components: main restricted


I deleted third-party.sources as recommended for same file in earlier statement and problem is resolved. I am guessing that I must have specified retaining old third party repos when I upgraded a couple days ago from 22.04.
Note to self: DON'T EVER DO THAT AGAIN.
Thanks for the help here.
